# "foo++;" crashes my prime number finder

Tags: arrays, primes

Today I tried to do program that will trying to find prime numbers, add them to array:"arraiki" and then check if it works properly by comparing array:"arraiki" with auto filled array:"myInput".
But unfortunately it crashes itself when im trying to change value of temp, that is index of array:"arraiki".

Mini-version.

```
int temp = 0;

{

  loop, if...

  arraiki[temp] = i;

  temp++;

}
```

---

Whole code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string prime(int &range)

{
string answer="";

for (int i=2; i<range; i++)
{
    if (range%i==0) answer = "NOPE";
}

if(answer=="NOPE") return "NAH";
else return "TRUTH";
}



int main()
{

int arraiki[] = {};
int myInput[] = {2,5,7};
int temp = 0;

for (int i = 2; i<100; i++)
{
    if(prime(i)=="TRUTH")
    {
        arraiki[temp] = i;
/// --> causes problem     temp++;

/*error.log()*/ cout << "temp is: " << temp << " value of arraiki is:     " <<arraiki[temp] << " and i: " << i <<  endl;
    }

}



/// SOON ™
/*
for (int =0; i<(sizeof(arraiki)/sizeof(arraiki[0])); i++)
{
     if(arraiki[i]==myInput[i])

                            cout << "OK AT: " << i << endl;

            else
                            cout << "SMTH WENT WRONG AT: " << i << endl;
}
*/
return 0;

}
```

---

Error "log" with temp++; turned OFF

temp is: 0 value of arraiki is:     2 and i: 2

temp is: 0 value of arraiki is:     3 and i: 3

temp is: 0 value of arraiki is:     5 and i: 5

temp is: 0 value of arraiki is:     7 and i: 7

temp is: 0 value of arraiki is:     11 and i: 11

temp is: 0 value of arraiki is:     13 and i: 13

temp is: 0 value of arraiki is:     17 and i: 17

temp is: 0 value of arraiki is:     19 and i: 19

temp is: 0 value of arraiki is:     23 and i: 23

temp is: 0 value of arraiki is:     29 and i: 29

(...)

temp is: 0 value of arraiki is:     97 and i: 97

So, It shows prime values properly.

PS: What I could do better? Please be Honest.

Comment: If he solved your problem, the stackoverflow community would appreciate if you would accept his answer... (He'd appreciate it, too.) Thanks.

Comment: Don't return strings instead of bool. Don't assume you can compare char*'s by `==`, even if they are const (use `strcmp()`, `strncmp()` or better yet, `std::string`). Develop a habbit of pre-incrementing (i.e., `++i` instead of `i++`) whenever you can. Don't assume arrays get 'magically expanded', they are of constant size (well, normally...), use `std::vector<int>` and `arraiki.push_back(i);` instead.

Comment: Now it's accepted, ty for reminder.

Comment: @lorro Thanks, especially for incrementing part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what language you're in, but it looks like C++.  If it is, you have to declare the number of elements in `arraiki` before you can use a non-zero index to the array.  Try:

```
int arraiki[100] ;
```

Instead of

```
int arraiki[] = {};
```

Comment: Works properly, ty.